# Pyhonic use of if statements for inequalities applied to chunked list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, inequality

Given the following lists in Python:

```
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000] #8 values, 7 intervals
v1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] #7 values
v2 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] #7 letters
```

I want to check whether a number is contained in any interval, and return another value based on which interval this is.

Example:

```
1. My test value is 1111
2. It belongs to the second interval: 1000 < 1111 < 5000
3. Hence I need to return b
```

I would address the problem by:

1. Creating chunks of `l1`
2. Iterating over each chunk
3. Writing one if statement for each chunk
4. Return the letter corresponding to the correct chunk

I can create chunks of it by looking at every consecutive pair of numbers:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq)))

for group in chunker(l1, 2):
   print(group)
```

This returns:

```
[0, 1000]
[1000, 5000]
[5000, 10000]
[10000, 20000]
[20000, 30000]
[30000, 40000]
[40000, 50000]
[50000]
```

**My questions:**

1. Is there a Pythonic way of writing those if statements instead of
   having one for each chunk? What if I have 1,000 chunks?
2. If there is, how to deal with the last chunk without creating a specific case for it?

Comment: Can the chunks have more than 2 values?

Comment: Not in my use case. There, they are meant to represent the upper and lower bound of a certain chunk.

Comment: Is there a known maximum value that can be appended to `l1`? 1e9?  1e99?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a generator to get the result:

```
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000]
v2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

value = 1111

result = next((v for v, i, j in zip(v2, l1[:-1], l1[1:]) if value in range(i, j)), None)
```

Output:

```
>>> result
'b'
```

By adding a default of `None` as second argument of `next()`, you can handle cases when not found as well:

```
value = -50

result = next((v for v, i, j in zip(v2, l1[:-1], l1[1:]) if value in range(i, j)), None)

>>> result
# None
```

If you just wanted the index, you can use `enumerate` instead:

```
result = next((v for v, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(l1[:-1], l1[1:])) if value in range(i, j)), None)

>>> result
# 1
```

**Explanation:**

The result line consists of a few parts:

```
next(iterator [, default])
```

This is a function to retrieve the next item in the `iterator` passed in the argument.  The `default` serves to return a default value if a `StopIteration` is encountered.  The `iterator` in question is the generator here (broken down for clarity):

```
(
  v                                  # point 4
    for v, i, j                      # point 2
      in zip(v2, l1[:-1], l1[1:])    # point 1
    if value in range(i, j)          # point 3
)
```

1. The `zip` function collates the `lists` that were passed, so that `v2[0]`, `l1[:-1][0]` and `l1[1:][0]` forms into a tuple `('a', 0, 1000)`, and so on for each index.
2. The `for v, i, j` serves to extract the elements within the tuple.
3. The `if value in range(i, j)` serves to check that `1111` is within the range between `range(0, 1000)`.
4. If it's a match, `v` is returned.  If not, continue to the next iteration.

Comment: Rather than `b`, it should return its index, e.g. `1`. Also, it would be great if you could explain the result line :)

Comment: That's even simpler then, you don't even need `v2` at all? `next((v for v, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(l1[:-1], l1[1:])) if value in range(i, j)), None)`

Answer (score 4):

You can `zip` list `l1` and `l1[1:]` which will make the intervals in a fashion that you need. And for some extra pointers you can incorporate binary search into this since the intervals are sorted, that I'll leave for you to optimise. The current runtime of this algorithm is `O(n)` you can reduce the runtime to `O(log(n))`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000]
v2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
element = 1111
interval = []
letter = None
for index,(left,right) in enumerate(zip(l1,l1[1:])):
    if left <= element <= right:
        interval = [left,right]
        letter = index
        break
if letter:
    print("answer is ",v2[letter])
    print("interval is" ,interval)
else:
    print("No interval found")
```

**EDIT**

I have added a algorithm using the `bisect` module in python 
it produces the same output but uses binary search hence it should be faster and runs in `O(log(n))`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import bisect
li = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000]
v2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
element = 1111
index = bisect.bisect(li, element)
if index == 0 or index == len(li):
    print("No interval found")
else:
    print("answer is",v2[index - 1])
    print("interval is",li[index - 1], li[index])
```

OUTPUT

```
answer is  b
interval is [1000, 5000]
```

Comment: @Frank please tell which portion did you find hard to read. I`ll try my best to improve

Comment: mostly "index,(left,right) in enumerate(zip(l1,l1[1:]))". enumerate a zip to integer and tuple of two integers makes me need a brain specialist :-D I'm also not a big friend of break inside a for loop. Don't guess me wrong. That is only my opinion. Code that works... works.

Comment: @Frank I have added a second algorithm an improved one if I may say so myself.

Answer (score 3):

Straight from the itertools recipe book:

```
def get_thing(value):

    def pairwise(iterable):
        from itertools import tee
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return zip(a, b)

    interval_ranges = [
        0,
        100,
        500,
        1000
    ]

    # There are four interval ranges, so three intervals.
    things = [
        "A", # 0-100
        "B", # 100-500
        "C" # 500-1000
    ]

    for (begin, end), thing in zip(pairwise(interval_ranges), things):
        if begin <= value < end: # modify this to suit your needs. Is the range inclusive/exclusive?
            return thing
    return None


def main():

    thing = get_thing(400)
    print(thing)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
B
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to get the corresponding interval index and use that to query `v2`.
This should do it:

```
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000] #8 values, 7 intervals
v2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'] #7 letters


def intervals(l):
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        yield i, l[i:i+2]


def interval_value(val, interval_list, value_list):
    for i, interval in intervals(interval_list):
        if interval[0] <= val <= interval[1]:
            return value_list[i]


print(interval_value(1111, l1, v2))
print(interval_value(0, l1, v2))
print(interval_value(51000, l1, v2))
print(interval_value(40000, l1, v2))
```

Output:

```
b
a
None
f
```

You don't need the `v1` values - you can work with the index on `v2` directly

Answer (score 3):

Though other answer is useful but almost all of them is finding interval not desire output from `v2`

```
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000]
v2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
element = 1111
def get_interval(l1):
    for index, left, right in zip(range(len(l1)), l1, l1[1:]):
        if left <= element <= right:
            return v2[index]

>>> print("answer is:" ,get_interval(element))
>>> answer is: b
```

Answer (score 1):

This works only with chunks of len 2.

```py
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000] #8 values, 7 intervals
# v1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] #7 values
v2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']  # 7 letters

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq)))

def chunk_with_value(list_of_chunks, value):
    """returns the chunk if the value is inside the range"""
    for chunk in list_of_chunks:
        if chunk[0] < value < chunk[1]:
            return chunk

def chunk_to_letter(value_list, letter_list, chunk):
    """returns the letter based on the index of the first chunk element"""
    for i, value in enumerate(l1):
        if value == chunk[0]:
            return v2[i]


chunks = chunker(l1, 2)
chunk = chunk_with_value(chunks, 1111)
print(chunk)  # [1000, 5000]
print(chunk_to_letter(l1, v2, chunk))  # b
```